# Phonegap access to native dropdown in Android

Tags: android, cordova

i have a question about phonegap(android).

i use as framework Kendo UI and want to access the native dropdown menü.

if i write this code, it will be opened Kendo Dropdown GUI

```
<select id="dropDownList">
    <option>Item 1</option>
    <option>Item 2</option>
    <option>Item 3</option>
</select>
```

But that's not, what i want to, it must looks like so :

[image]

i would be happy, if you help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe its impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Using the above `select` markup will use Android's native drop-down implementation.

At least this is what I've observed when using:

- Kendo Mobile UI framework build <= 2014.1.1409
- Cordova 2.9.0/3.3.0
- Building apps via cordova CLI and/or PhoneGap Build service

However, one caveat is on some older Android OS's, the `select` tag is not recognized.  Instead, use the following:

`<form id="dropdown-form">
    <input type="radio" name="sameName" value="1">1<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sameName" value="2">2<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sameName" value="3">3
</form>`